# Is it possible to choose the controls that I want in a HTML <audio> tag?

Tags: html

Can I choose only the controls that I want which will be displayed in the audio player? For instance, I only want the play button to be there and not the other options like the seek, mute and download buttons.

Here is the code that I'm currently using and it shows all the options:

```
<audio controls>
   <source src = "/path/to/audio" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Even if you could, and I sincerely doubt you can, the user could just go into their dev console and change it back to the default. `<audio>` is for when you want to present audio to the user, not control how they use it. There's a reason Spotify doesn't use the built-in `<audio>` tags, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. However, you could create your own controls and your own player or use a third party player.